# allow php to write log files

Tags: php, linux, file-io, permissions

I have a php script I want to create log files with. But it wont do it, permission denied.
syntactically, i think my code is correct for writing files, but I don’t know how to (safely)
allow php to make files in a directory.

```
> [Wed May 07 07:01:28.827861 2014] [:error] [pid 2457] [client
> 10.0.0.123:63383] PHP Warning:  fopen(Log filename: 1399460488.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/j0h/www/test/iv.php on line 7, referer:
> http://10.0.0.123/test/
```

this is a linux server using php5.4
here is the code I am trying to use to write the file:
Line 7 starts with $handle ...

```
<?php
//Time... for some logs
$t=time();
//create Log filename based of Epoch
$LogName =  $t . ".txt";
$handle = fopen($LogName, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$LogName); 

$file = fopen( $LogName, "w" );
if( $file == false )
{
   echo ( "Error in opening new file" );
   exit();
}
fwrite( $file, "This is  a simple test\n" );
fclose( $file );
?>
```

Comment: Is the file read-only?

Comment: I want to create the log files on the fly. They do not exist yet.

Comment: you need to give the iv.php file 777 permission
in the properties - for read write files.
http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/assets/777.png

Comment: what about 777 permission then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not an php issue. It's the filesystem that prevents writing access. There are several solutions: Give the directory 777 rights, let your webuser own the directory or let it join a group that has permissions, ...

Navigate to the log directory and try `sudo chmod -R 777 .`

Comment: chmod 777 test/ was sufficient. Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer : add the write permission to the directory you are writing log to :

```
chmod -R +w /home/j0h/www/test/
```

However, for a more secure way, you should write your log to a specific log directory, without any php or executable file in it.

Comment: Yeah, Im just knocking out a idea I had, and got jammed. but i certainly will take your advice when Im im done tooling with this.